# React Native AsyncStorage async function return

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, async-await

I have a helper function:

```
export async function isFavorite(id) {
  try {
    let favorites = await AsyncStorage.getItem("@rn-food-app:favorites");
    if (favorites) {
      return JSON.parse(favorites).includes(id);
    }
    return false;
  } catch (error) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

which I'm calling like this:

```
class DetailScreen extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      recipe: null,
      isFavorite: false,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const { route } = this.props;

    if (route.params && route.params.recipeId) {
      const recipe = getRecipe(route.params.recipeId);
      this.setState(
        {
          recipe,
        },
        () => {
          this.checkIfFavorite();
        }
      );
    }
  }

  checkIfFavorite() {
    const { recipe } = this.state;

    console.log(isFavorite(recipe.id));
  }

... ... ...
```

but the `console.log()` returns something like this

```
Promise {
  "_U": 0,
  "_V": 0,
  "_W": null,
  "_X": null,
}
```

instead of a `bool`.

I can make it work like this:

```
export async function isFavorite(id) {
  try {
    return await AsyncStorage.getItem("@rn-food-app:favorites");
  } catch (error) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

and then in the `DetailScreen component`

```
  checkIfFavorite() {
    const { recipe } = this.state;

    isFavorite(recipe.id)
      .then((res) => {
        const favorite = JSON.parse(res).includes(recipe.id);
        console.log(favorite);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  }
```

This works but why doesn't the approach above work? I wanted to extract all this logic into a helper function so I can simply call `isFavorite: bool` inside my components without extra logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are logging out Promise instead of an actual result of a Promise, something like this would:

```
 async checkIfFavorite() {
    const { recipe } = this.state;
    const isFav = await isFavorite(recipe.id) 

    console.log(isFav);
  }
```

or something along those lines would work

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are not resolving your promise correctly thats why you get that weird looking console.log

Take a look at this example and change it to your needs - when getting the item from AsyncStorage I am calling 2x .then() calls and 1x .catch() call.

You can store and retrieve your data like this with AsyncStorage:

```
  const storeData = async (key, value) => {
    try {
      await AsyncStorage.setItem(key, value); 
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  const getData = async key => {
    try {
      const data = await AsyncStorage.getItem(key);
      if (data !== null) {
        console.log(data);
        return data;
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
```

then call getData with the key name like you stored your value wherever you want and set the key to a state value.

Store the value:

```
storeData("@rn-food-app:favorites", the value);
```

get the value:

```
  await getData"@rn-food-app:favorites") 
    .then((data) => data)
    .then((value) => this.setState({ isFavorite: value }))
    .catch((err) => console.log("AsyncStorageErr: " + err));
```

Comment: Yes this approach works, I just thought that the first promise inside `getData` would handle this and you won't need to call `await getData() ...` later on